# Create a radio button filter based on "Created Date" attribute using jquery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt, filtering

I’m currently loading a number of list items through a customised Content Query Web Part.

And XSLT attribute associated with each of these items is the Created Date.

An example of the mark up below.

```
<div class="item" createddate="2014-01-22 13:02:52" language="French">Content</div>
<div class="item" createddate="2014-01-28 13:02:52" language="German">Content</div>
<div class="item" createddate="2013-12-18 13:02:52" language="Italian">Content</div>
```

What I need to do is create a radio button filter where the values are:

- Last 30 days
- Last 90 days

When either of these radio buttons are selected, it will hide and show the items based on their date value.

How could the filter be created (through jquery/javascript) that would hide and show these items based on their created date?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Parse the `createddate` attribute using `new Date(date-time-string)`, subtract it from today (`new Date()`), convert it into days.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the `createddate` attribute using `new Date(date-time-string)`, subtract it from today (`new Date()`), and convert it into days.

Chrome parses your existing date-time format correctly; Firefox currently does not. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) you need to separate the date and time with a `T` instead of a space. We can make the change in JavaScript if your HTML is immutable:

```
$('.radioclass').on('change', function (e) {
    $radio = $(this);
    $('.item').hide().filter(function (i, el) {
        var datestr = $(el).attr('createddate').replace(' ', 'T'); //ISO-8601
        var createddate = new Date(datestr);
        var nowdate = new Date();
        // subtracting dates returns a number in milliseconds
        var diffdays = Math.floor((nowdate - createddate) / (1000*60*60*24));
        return (diffdays <= $radio.val());
    }).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/GBR3t/

Comment: `new Date($(el).attr('createddate'))` leads to an invalid `Date` when you try to create it.  That's not a valid input string for the object.

Comment: @talemyn Not for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Hmmm . . . when I was testing the values, it was not giving a valid Date . . . interesting.  (I can't check your Fiddle . . . site is blocked by the firewall).

Comment: From what I saw, it was choking on the format of the date . . . it didn't like `2014-01-22`, but was fine with `2014/01/22`.

Comment: Blazemonger - Thank you for this. The fiddle looks great and I'll try it in my environment now. From a novice point of view, what does the "i" and "el" do in the filter function?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do some logic with js for this, but why not use jQuery to do so? I'm going to recommend using [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com/) for this. Make sure it is loaded **before** the script.

With moment we can get the current time and determine if it is before a set date.

```
var t = moment();

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".items").hide();

    var i = t.duration(30, 'd');
    var o = t.duration(90, 'd');
    var thirtyday = t.add(i);
    var ninetyday = t.add(o);

    $(".items").each(function() {
        var a = $(this).attr("createddate");
        var d = moment(a, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
        if(d.isAfter(thirtyday) && d.isBefore(ninetyday)) {
            $(this).addClass("lastninetydays").addClass("lastthirtydays");
        }
    });
});
```

And then you can show/hide those items with classes based on the radio value.

If you add a time tick, you can get even more dynamic results.

```
var t = moment();

setInterval(function() {
    t = moment();
    updateListItems();
    radioChange($(".radio").val());
}, 1000);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".items").hide();

    var i = t.duration(30, 'd');
    var o = t.duration(90, 'd');
    var thirtyday = t.add(i);
    var ninetyday = t.add(o);

    $(".radio").change(function() {
        radioChange($(this).val());
    }
});

function updateListItems () {
    $(".items").each(function() {
        var a = $(this).attr("createddate");
        var d = moment(a, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
        if(d.isAfter(thirtyday) && d.isBefore(ninetyday)) {
            $(this).addClass("lastninetydays").addClass("lastthirtydays");
        }
    });
}

function radioChange (val) {
    //show/hide list items based on what the radio value is.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting moment JS. It looks fantastic. Unfortunately I couldn't get the above to work in a codepen environment. Thanks for responding. The library looks brilliant.